# wso2 iot Signature or Message Authentication invalid

Tags: wso2-iot

-WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0 RC-
I configured ip, created certificates, started broker server and  then core. Core gives error, what do I missed?

[IoT-Core] ERROR - {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.grant.jwt.JWTBearerGrantHandler} Signature or Message Authentication invalid.
Exception in thread "Thread-31" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.OAuthRequestInterceptor.apply(OAuthRequestInterceptor.java:104)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.targetRequest(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:158)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:88)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.apisGet(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherServiceImpl.publishAPI(APIPublisherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.publishAPIs(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler.access$500(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:30)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.webapp.publisher.APIPublisherStartupHandler$1.run(APIPublisherStartupHandler.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 5):

This happens because in order to publish APIs, IoT core uses JWT grant type. For that, request header should have to sign with the public certificate of the iot core server. So you need to add the public certificate of your keystore to the identity provider. For that, please follow the below steps.

- run the following command inside from /repository/resources/security direcotory `keytool -export -alias wso2carbon -rfc -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file server.pem -storepass wso2carbon`.
- Then open the `server.pem` from a text editor and remove `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` lines as well as the new lines.
- Then copy the content of the certificate and paste it into `<IoTs-Home>/conf/identity/identity-provider/iot-default.xml` under `<Certificate>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue with WSO2 IoT 3.3.0:
1. I ran ./change-ip.sh with exemple.com 
2. I created a new keystore (exemple.com.jks) [with signed certificate](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores#CreatingNewKeystores-Addingthepublickeytoclient-truststore.jks)
3. I followed the steps described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IOTS330/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+IoT+Server) to change the default keystore to my new keystore exemple.com.jks 
4. enable the debug mode for wire and feign. 
5. start the ./iot-server.sh start 
6. open https://exemple.com:9443/devicemgt portal 
7. enter the admin user account and get the error as shows below:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:34,015] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2
```

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:34,021] ERROR {auth-module} -  An exception thrown when executing the script '/app/modules/login.js'. {auth-module}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:34,025] ERROR {auth-module} -  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: Failed to retrieve scopes from access token {auth-module}
org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.integration.client.exception.APIMClientOAuthException: Failed to retrieve scopes from access token (/devicemgt/app/modules/login.js#31)
```

Full stacketrace:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,061] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "POST /token?tenantDomain=carbon.super HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,064] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Authorization: Basic Z1UxanlPOUxvS3JlWGFYb1V2c1NqWTc1VkdBYTpKU1kxc0R...NWkt4ZmdFSmNh[\r]
[\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,064] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,064] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Length: 826[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,064] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Host: wazidmg.cf:8243[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,064] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,065] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,065] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,065] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,065] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6WyJkZXZpY2VtZ3QiXSwibmJmIjoxNTM1OTA3Mzgws_eitWu0w30lyqZGU9P79f5y-FRIYkTOuWs-MVckTqpuktzdt51uNfB7iJygFNmDHMXTDQRQZJ4D9vWy0tRx1O_nU8rdBtcn8e-SP0zJTEvAEXST__lJHinNVeq1op2SqLSciP-jfvlFZo8ooF0KRqvhqsyX2Je3MDnLir8O22pv3PW3-Ttz-yHOxQpeSXw5RrPAILjWkLPDqqx9XrEtgqJBrSH115TumNiyvoGPaLpa67jddIfFy70wjIBYGkSqRYGtWOWLz3q2wC5QNrK02wCCJhLf9nM60mjhDeoAo6pVjI4xnpacTOnkDJ8WLnBkhNNvTNRD-88x2p1LYVvDww&scope=apim%3Aapi_create+apim%3Aapi_view+apim%3Aapi_publish+apim%3Asubscribe+apim%3Atier_view+apim%3Atier_manage+apim%3Asubscription_view+apim%3Asubscription_block" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,284] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 > "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,693] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Frame-Options: DENY[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,693] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,693] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,694] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 16:56:21 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,694] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,694] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Length: 92[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,694] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,694] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,694] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,694] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "{"error_description":"Signature or Message Authentication invalid.","error":"invalid_grant"}" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:56:21,738] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 > "POST /token?tenantDomain=carbon.super HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Authorization: Basic Z1UxanlPOUxvS3JlWGFYb1V2c1NqWTc1VkdBYTpKU1kxc0RwVXNmblpETERvTE9NWkt4ZmdFSmNh[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}

TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Length: 828[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Host: wazidmg.cf:8243[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,932] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6WyJkZXZpY2VtZ3QiXSwibmJmIjoxNTM1OTA3NTEzLCJVc2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaXNzIjoid3NvMi5vcmdcL3Byb2R1Y3RzXC9pb3QiLCJleHAiOjE1MzU5Njc1MTMsImlhdCI6MTUzNTkwNzUxMywianRpIjoiMTUzNTkwNzUxMzg5NjE0MTk3NTMwMDYifQ.iD7Uu-leHyi-ya1PG8V_AiMN-n-HAi037afm_utsKewe1er2hdPeEegJ0zetLFNGpPjw0D7ye5IJrdSQr7zi5RXC2-DD2nZlGPK9KPP5K2_9t050oOAPIKcnQftt8B6aagGLhVsEKsMz10xaGj3G5IVn1Rc4nz114R2CeYtTa4_DRlfrVePf6KqvXRpPRYrpJ642x7jScjcfWn4x6MePF9Qr9-_k5UYp03mZcgJIkdlBd1plRzt5pTvHNATDxcEJcw4HLMVJMSOfbWSqpsUbZr6n0g6zd0fslgee7T8d-QcbTnhdwnxoLJyJkVVytskpSHXcNgfGM6UG-IIBx7EWSA&scope=apim%3Aapi_create+apim%3Aapi_view+apim%3Aapi_publish+apim%3Asubscribe+apim%3Atier_view+apim%3Atier_manage+apim%3Asubscription_view+apim%3Asubscription_block" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,961] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 > "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "X-Frame-Options: DENY[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 16:58:33 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Content-Length: 92[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Server: WSO2 Carbon Server[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:33,995] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "{"error_description":"Signature or Message Authentication invalid.","error":"invalid_grant"}" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-09-02 16:58:34,014] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2
```

I don’t know what I missed...